# Exception with JunitParams running instrumentation tests on Android 19 and below

Tags: android-espresso, android-testing

#### Description

I am seeing an exception when using the JunitParams runner on Android 19 and below.

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Write simple test suite and execute on Android 19 or lower with latest Android Testing Support Libaries

#### Code

The following test suite will reproduce the issue

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class SimpleTest {
    @Test
    @Parameters({ "false", "true" })
    public void simpleParameterizedTest(boolean enabled) {
        // Should execute and pass
    }
}
```

#### Expected Behavior

Tests should execute and pass.

#### Actual Behavior

Tests are not run because "no tests are found"

#### Logs

I checked the logs and I see the following exception occurring.

```
09-07 12:17:01.187 3338-3355/com.twilio.video.test W/dalvikvm: Exception Ljava/util/regex/PatternSyntaxException; thrown while initializing Ljunitparams/naming/MacroSubstitutionNamingStrategy;
09-07 12:17:01.187 3338-3355/com.twilio.video.test E/TestExecutor: Fatal exception when running tests
                                                                   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                       at junitparams.internal.TestMethod$1.computeValue(TestMethod.java:40)
                                                                       at junitparams.internal.TestMethod$1.computeValue(TestMethod.java:35)
                                                                       at junitparams.internal.Memoizer.get(Memoizer.java:11)
                                                                       at junitparams.internal.TestMethod.describe(TestMethod.java:116)
                                                                       at junitparams.internal.ParameterisedTestClassRunner.describeParameterisedMethod(ParameterisedTestClassRunner.java:161)
                                                                       at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.describeMethod(JUnitParamsRunner.java:502)
                                                                       at junitparams.internal.ParametrizedTestMethodsFilter.filteredMethods(ParametrizedTestMethodsFilter.java:30)
                                                                       at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.getListOfMethods(JUnitParamsRunner.java:498)
                                                                       at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.getDescription(JUnitParamsRunner.java:487)
                                                                       at org.junit.runners.Suite.describeChild(Suite.java:123)
                                                                       at org.junit.runners.Suite.describeChild(Suite.java:27)
                                                                       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.shouldRun(ParentRunner.java:434)
                                                                       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.filter(ParentRunner.java:382)
                                                                       at org.junit.runner.manipulation.Filter.apply(Filter.java:97)
                                                                       at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder$LenientFilterRequest.getRunner(TestRequestBuilder.java:413)
                                                                       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
                                                                       at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
                                                                       at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:375)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)
                                                                    Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length near index 40:
                                                                   (?=\{[^\}]{0,50}\})|(?<=\{[^\}]{0,50}\})
                                                                                                           ^
                                                                       at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:411)
                                                                       at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:394)
                                                                       at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:381)
                                                                       at junitparams.naming.MacroSubstitutionNamingStrategy.<clinit>(MacroSubstitutionNamingStrategy.java:13)
                                                                        ... 19 more
```

#### Versions

Here is a snippet from my `build.gradle` file.

```
androidTestCompile 'pl.pragmatists:JUnitParams:1.1.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
```

Answer (score 2):

We've just fixed that issue in JUnitParams and released new version.

Now you can fetch the newest version and start using it with Android 19 and below!

`androidTestCompile 'pl.pragmatists:JUnitParams:1.1.1'`

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the newer versions of Studio, you would need to write:

```
testImplementation 'pl.pragmatists:JUnitParams:1.1.1'
```

but not `androidTestImplementation ...` which does not work.